# Coordenadas de uma imagem PyGame

Tags: python, jogos, coordenadas, pygame

Como eu posso conseguir as coordenadas x e y de uma imagem em PyGame? Preciso disto para um jogo onde tenho que fazer com que o tiro saia exatamente abaixo de um inimigo.
Este é o código:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import sys
import random
import pygame
print pygame.init()  #inicia todo o módulo pygame (pygame.init() retorna algo, não faz a inicialização completa por isso so print
x_player, y_player = 650, 440
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 500))  # screen's size width and height
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders v1.0.0")  # name of the screen
pygame.display.flip()
invaders = pygame.image.load(
    "C:\\Users\\bernardo\\Documents\\IFC\\Programação\\SpaceInvaders-my_own\\space-invaders.jpeg").convert()
player = pygame.image.load(
    "C:\\Users\\bernardo\\Documents\\IFC\\Programação\\SpaceInvaders-my_own\\28006.png").convert()  # loads the image
    #  of the player and put it on a variable
mother_ship = pygame.image.load(
    "C:\\Users\\bernardo\\Documents\\IFC\\Programação\\SpaceInvaders-my_own\\mother_ship.png").convert()
lifes = pygame.image.load(
    "C:\\Users\\bernardo\\Documents\\IFC\\Programação\\SpaceInvaders-my_own\\28007.png").convert()
shots = pygame.image.load(
    "C:\\Users\\bernardo\\Documents\\IFC\\Programação\\SpaceInvaders-my_own\\shots_and_bombs2.png").convert()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player_size = player.get_size()
move_x = 0

x_invaders, y_invaders = 60, 60
lifes_list = [lifes, lifes, lifes]
x_mother = 0
invaders_matrix = [[invaders] * 11] * 5
existe_nave = False
start = True
while len(lifes_list) != 0:
screen.fill([0, 0, 0]) # color of the screen (rgb)
screen.blit(player, [(x_player / 2), y_player]) # initial position of player
clock.tick(35) # are going to happen just movements on 23 frames per second
screen.blit(shots, (invaders_matrix[random.randint(0, 4)][random.randint(0, 10)].get_rect().centerx,
        invaders_matrix[random.randint(0, 4)][random.randint(0, 10)].get_rect().centery))

x_invaders, y_invaders = 105, 125
for invader in range(len(invaders_matrix)):
    for invad in range(len(invaders_matrix[invader])):
        screen.blit(invaders_matrix[invader][invad], [x_invaders, y_invaders])
        x_invaders += 45
    x_invaders = 105
    y_invaders += 30

if existe_nave and (x_mother < 700):
    screen.blit(mother_ship, [x_mother, 35])
    x_mother += 4.5
    screen.blit(mother_ship, [x_mother, 35])

elif random.randint(0, 800) == 0:
    existe_nave = True
    x_mother = 0

width_for_lifes = 680
for icon_lifes in lifes_list:
    width_for_lifes -= 50
    screen.blit(icon_lifes, (width_for_lifes, 15))

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
        start = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            move_x -= 10
            start = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            move_x += 10
            start = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            move_x = 0
            start = False

if x_player >= 1280:
    x_player = 1280
if x_player <= 25:
    x_player = 25

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text = font.render("Lifes", 1, (0, 255, 85))
screen.blit(text, (450, 15))

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text = font.render("Score", 1, (0, 255, 85))
screen.blit(text, (20, 15))

x_player += move_x

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois que você coloca uma imagem na imagem principal (tela) usando uma chamada ao método "blit" como esse código faz, a imagem se torna parte da imagem principal:

o Blit é como bater um carimbo numa folha de papel: o que você sabe é onde mandou bater o carimbo - se mexer o carimbo de lugar, só usando os olhos para "ver" onde está a imagem. Só que quando programamos jogos nesse estilo, "ver" é uma operação cara - nesse caso, quase inviável.
(é possível, mas você teria que usar reconhecimento de imagens e uma série de técnicas de programação quase uma centena de vezes mais sofisticadas que o jogo em si)

Para saber onde está cada nave invasora e ali colocar o tiro, você deve guardar as coordenadas de cada nave em estruturas de dados na memória -

No seu caso, as linhas

```
     x_invaders += 45
x_invaders = 105
y_invaders += 30
```

posicionam os alienígenas, de forma "artesanal" - e os dados sobre cada alienígena são descartados e recalculados em tempo real no próximo quadro.

Essa era uma técnica necessária nso videogames com poucos KB de memória onde esse tipo de jogo foi criado pela primeira vez. Hoje em dia, o que vale a pena é você criar um objeto em memória para cada nave invasora (e outros elementos em jogo), e associar os dados de cada elemento a ele mesmo. Assim, qualquer alienígena na matriz vai ter a informação de onde ele está.

O Pygame propícia uma classe bem legal, que tem interação com as classes de `Group` do jogo, para servir como base para seus objetos: a classe `pygame.Sprite` .

Quando você sua seus inimigos derivados de pygame.Sprite, por exemplo, usualmente eles terão um objeto `pygame.Rect` associado - que contém todas as coordenadas do inimigo, a cada momento (o seu programa que atualiza essas coordenadas). Mas ao fazer isso, você pode ter a coordenada do centro na horizontal, do lado de baixo de cada invasor simplesmente fazendo:

```
x, y = invader.rect.centerx, invader.rect.bottom
```

Fique a vontade para me escrever em privado se quiser mais orientações sobre esse jogo - estou trabalhando em um projeto semelhante com meus alunos. (meu contato está no perfil)

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!!

Comment: Ótima resposta! :)